# The computer turns on but there is no display: VGA debug light on

Tags: computer-building

I am building a computer, here is the [component list](https://fr.pcpartpicker.com/list/Ch8dwg):

- AMD Ryzen 5 5600X 3.7 GHz 6-Core Processor
- MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK MAX WIFI ATX AM4 Motherboard
- Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro 32 GB (2 x 16 GB) DDR4-3600 CL18 Memory
- Samsung 980 Pro 1 TB M.2-2280 PCIe 4.0 X4 NVME Solid State Drive
- MSI GAMING X GeForce RTX 4060 Ti 8 GB Video Card
- Corsair 4000D Airflow ATX Mid Tower Case
- MSI MAG A750GL PCIE5 750 W 80+ Gold Certified Fully Modular ATX Power Supply
- Microsoft Windows 11 Home Retail - Download 64-bit

The problem is, the computer turns on but there is no display. And the VGA EZ debug LED is red on the motherboard. The GPU, RAM sticks are lit with their RBG lights so I'm assuming they are functioning properly.

I have tried many things:

1. Unplugging, repluggin the GPU
2. Removed a RAM stick to leave only one
3. Cleared the CMOS by removing the battery, waiting 15 minutes and putting back in.
4. Cleared the CMOS using the jumper.
5. Tried plugging a 1050Ti that doesn't require any power supply, this GPU worked perfectly well on my previous setup.

I'm at loss at where the problem might be. I suspect it is not the GPU's fault, as I have tried plugging it on and off several times, and the RBG light is on. I could be using the wrong PSIe cables tho (Thing is, it still doesn't work with the 1050Ti so I suspect it is not the problem).
I do not think it is the RAMs or CPUs fault either as their debug lights are not lit.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Dumb question (or maybe not): Are you connecting the video cable (HDMI/DP) to the graphics card, not directly to the motherboard, right?

Comment: The EZ Debug LED consists of four LEDs labeled CPU, DRAM, VGA, and BOOT, normally located near the 24-pin power connector or along the edge of the motherboard. If not all are lit, this could point to the problem. ([link](https://www.electronicshub.org/ez-debug-led/))

Comment: From Harrys link: "VGA LED: This LED is related to the graphics card or the display output. If it stays lit, it indicates a potential problem with the graphics card or its connection to the motherboard." have you plugged the power cable into the GPU?

Comment: @ChanganAuto No question is dumb! I'm connecting the DP cable to the graphic card yeah, not the motherboard.

Comment: @harrymc Only the VGA debug led is lit, the others are okay. I also did everything mentionned in your link, except updating the BIOS as it is a brand new computer and I have no way to access graphical interface.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes I have plugged the power cable into the GPU. I thought maybe I plugged it wrong, but then I tried an old working 1050 Ti which doesn't require any power cable, and I had the same issue with the VGA led being lit.

Comment: Last advice regarding the BIOS update : See [link](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-B550-TOMAHAWK/support).

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I just read that and the "How to flash BIOS" pdf, but how can I do it if my screen doesn't display anything?

Comment: If the screen is completely blank, you need to fix the problem, which is most likely hardware. You might have some hardware mismatch or damage, but it's impossible to say where. You may need more tools for testing, or perhaps professional help.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for your help, I'll keep struggling and trying stuff and if nothing works I'll return the motherboard and get a new one. Whatta shame though.

Comment: SOLVED -- It was actually really stupid, I plugged the graphic cards on the wrong slot (there are two, and it's the upper one with silver borders that works). I feel really dumb but glad the problem it solved and I learned something. Hope it helps someone.